# Manually setting max and min on a verticalAxis

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, charts

I have a candlestick chart that is working great when the numbers being dealt with are large but when the numbers are small the vertical axis starts at the very top of my data and ends at the very bottom. For example if my max number in my XML is 12 and my min is 11 the charts top is 12 and the charts bottom is 11 with 11.2, 11.4, 11.6, 11.8 in between. How can I force the chart to do 22 to 1 on the vertical axis `({maxgraph+10} and {mingraph-10})`.
Please help.

Comment: I tried using maxGraph and minGraph + or - 10 and it said that those were both nonexistant values. Please provide code example if you know this will work in flex 3. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Flex3 but a quick look at the documentation suggest that you might want to define your own axis class in which you will be able to override [the adjustMinMax() method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/chartClasses/NumericAxis.html#adjustMinMax()) to do what you want.